# Prepare 2-sides cards with data source to print on A4

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a 2-sides card (50x50) that use *.csv file as data source *(single file for both card sides)*
Now I need to prepare it to print on A4. So I should put 20 cards on one A4. I've tried to import  indesigh file to A4 project and apply "Step and Repeat" to fill A4, but in this case:

- card's second side being lost
- seems data source link lost as well *(I see only the first side of the first card from csv file)*.

Here an example what I try to achieve:
[image]
Where csv file looks like:

```
Text A; 1 ; Text B ; 1
Text A; 2 ; Text B ; 2
Text A; 3 ; Text B ; 3
...
```

Option 2 is preferable to me.
How it is possible to do somethimg like this in indesgn?

Comment: I believe it's best/easiest if you keep your design document separate from the print document. So *first* make a 50x50 mm document and make all the cards, *then* save and place that InDesign document in an A4 document.

Comment: @Wolff do you mean save cards to pdf and import? I've tried this way, but i have few csv files with ~300+ records in each.. so, looking for some automation. Haven't found free 3th-party import. Going to try create script.

Comment: No, I mean use some automation to create the 50x50 mm cards in one document. Then place that *indd document* (yes you can do that) in *another* indd document which is A4. Keep the two problems of automating the card creation and placing them on A4 *separate*. Much easier to automate creation of single 50x50 mm pages than automating them in a grid.

Comment: Is the case still unsolved? It doesn't seem too hard for scripting. To load .csv data, to slice the data by 6 lines, and to put first half lines on a page and second half lines on next page. Etc.

Comment: @YuriKhristich i have no experience with scripting, and had no time to learn. So I'll try to do it when have a time. For now I just putted few cards on A4 pages and changed csv file to  contains few sources in single line, like: Text A; 1 ; Text B ; 1;Text A; 2 ; Text B ; 2;Text A; 3 ; Text B ; 3.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if you need a help with scripting.